# sqlsrv insert when columns vary

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have searched around the web but no luck.
Am new to SQLSRV and i was migrating from PHP MySQL to PHP SQL and am having trouble inserting data from a form as some fields are optional which makes the column number vary. I need help on how i can insert when  the column number varies.
thank you 
here is how my insert code looks like

```
// sql fields and values for main table
    $in_fields = array();
    $in_values = array();

    // prepare insertion
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $value = sql_escape($value);
            $in_fields[] = "[{$key}]";
            $in_values[] = "'{$value}'";
        }
    }       

    // prepare sql stmt
    if (!empty($in_fields)) {
        $sql = "INSERT into [table_name](";
        $sql .= implode(", ", $in_fields);
        $sql .= ") VALUES ()";

        if (executeSql($sql, $in_values)) {
            $success = "Successfully Added New Record";
        }
    }
```

The executeSql function looks like this

```
function executeSql($sql, $params) {
   global $conndb;
   $rs = sqlsrv_query($conndb, $sql, $params)or die("Db query error.<br />".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   return !$rs ? false : true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add placeholder values (`?`) in the `VALUES` part of your query, you will need a placeholder for every value you pass through - i.e. for every value in `$in_values`.

To do this you could have another array, that will just have a number of `?` as values, and then, like you have done for the fields, `implode` the array into the `VALUES`. Like so:

```
$in_fields = array();
$in_values = array();
$placeholders = array(); // new array   

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $value = sql_escape($value);
        $in_fields[] = "[{$key}]";
        $in_values[] = "'{$value}'";

        // add a placeholder to the array
        $placeholders[] = "?";
    }
}

if (!empty($in_fields)) {
    $sql = "INSERT into [table_name](";
    $sql .= implode(", ", $in_fields);
    $sql .= ") VALUES (" . implode(",", $placeholders) . ")";

    if (executeSql($sql, $in_values)) {
        $success = "Successfully Added New Record";
    }
}
```